# Difference in servers

Tags: hosting

I am trying to pick the best solution for my businesses.

Can someone explain to me the difference between a dedicated server and a virtual dedicated server?

Also do I even need either of these or could I go with an unlimited plan with host gator for 3.95 a month. My busiest site which is a news site for western Arizona get's about 30,000 uniques and 60,000 page views. My other sites are way less like 2000 uniques.

Comment: nice thread:http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=91367

Comment: 30K per what? minute/hour/day/month?

Comment: webhostingtalk.com is a good place to visit when you get to the stage of deciding which provider(s) to go with.  Rest of the question is too vague to make an informed comment.

Answer (score 2):

A dedicated server is an actualy pysical dedicated server in a datacenter somewhere. These typically cost more to hire/run.

A Virtual Private Server is a Virtual Machine running on a physical server (see VMWare ESXi, VirtualBox, KVM, Xen, OpenVZ, etc.). This means the provider can run more than one client on a server.

As for which would be best, only you can really tell with that.